# How to implement another class init in the current class?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Hello I am slightly new to this. I have a Background class which sets the background in the init method and in my main class I want to set up the background by use of the background class I created. Any ideas for this simple question?

Comment: create an object of backgroud class in main class and do ...

Comment: Background *background= [[Background alloc] init]; background.color = [UIColor redColor];//condition is that background shoudl contain a property called color of type UIColor

Comment: My background class' code is a parallax scrolling so is the color information needed? Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be as simple as writing this in the initialization code of your main class?

```
[[Background alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

in main , create a

-(id) initWithBackground:(Background*) theBackground;

Comment: - (id) initWithBackground:(Background*) theBackground;

Okay thanks! does that automatically utilize the code in the id init of Background? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add a property to main class of your Background class type and then alloc and init it from your main class when you want to set up the background.

in your main class header:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) Background *backgroundInstance;
```

in your main class implementation:

```
- setBackground {
  backgroundInstance = [[Background alloc] init]};
```

I am not sure though why you would need a Background class.

Comment: To set up a Parallex Scrolling for the Main Game?

Comment: It gives me an error: use of undeclared identifier backgroundInstance :/